# how to store xml nodes in array C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml document like this

```
<UpdateDefinition>
      <manufacturer>Newton Cars, Inc</manufacturer>
      <model>Newton1</model>
      <model>Newton2</model>
      <model>Newton3</model>
      <model>Newton4</model>
      <fwversion>A.02.14</fwversion>
      <description>Newton cars NOTE: Media LCD display may go blank for about 30 seconds on first reboot.</description>
      <notes>Refer to release notes.</notes>
      <date>4/25/2013</date>
      <md5hash>N6/DsMDwkkU4bCeQ3aPQWg==</md5hash>
</UpdateDefinition>
```

Im supposed to be extracting the info from the above xml and save it in an array for future comparison use. 
Any idea how?

Comment: You're looking for LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xd = XDocument.Parse(@"<UpdateDefinition>
      <manufacturer>Newton Cars, Inc</manufacturer>
      <model>Newton1</model>
      <model>Newton2</model>
      <model>Newton3</model>
      <model>Newton4</model>
      <fwversion>A.02.14</fwversion>
      <description>Newton cars NOTE: Media LCD display may go blank for about 30 seconds on first reboot.</description>
      <notes>Refer to release notes.</notes>
      <date>4/25/2013</date>
      <md5hash>N6/DsMDwkkU4bCeQ3aPQWg==</md5hash>
</UpdateDefinition>");

string[] models = xd.Root.Descendants("model").Select(xe => xe.Value).ToArray();
```

I get:

[image: models]

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in Xml.Linq:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(yourXMLFile);
var aa = doc.Descendants("UpdateDefinition").Select(d => new
{
    manufacturer = d.Element("manufacturer").Value,
    models = d.Elements("model").Select(e => e.Value).ToList(),
    fwversion = d.Element("fwversion").Value,
    description = d.Element("description").Value,
    notes = d.Element("notes").Value,
    date = d.Element("date").Value,
    md5hash = d.Element("md5hash").Value
}).ToList();
```

It will give you all the values and a list of models as well.